# What happened when do std::vector = std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following code:

```
struct Position{
   int id;
   Position(int _id){
       id = _id;
       qDebug()<<"Position"<<id;
   }

   ~Position(){
       qDebug()<<"~Position "<<id;
   }
};

    qDebug()<<"Init";
    std::vector<Position> vec1;
    vec1.emplace_back(1);
    std::vector<Position> vec2;
    vec2.emplace_back(2);
    std::vector<Position> vec3;
    vec3.emplace_back(3);

    qDebug()<<"Move";
    vec2 = vec1;

    qDebug()<<"---------------------------------";
```

What happens when I do = ? Shouldn't previous object vec2 be destructed?
I read this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/, but still not undestand what should happend with old vec2 object.

**Output:**

```
Init
Position 1
Position 2
Position 3
Move
---------------------------------
~Position  3
~Position  1
~Position  1
```

Why Position  2 not destructed at all?

Comment: Add print statements in the copy constructor. `Position(Position const& rhs): id(rhs.id) {std::cout << "Copy Construct " << id << "\n";}` and the assignment `Position& operator=(Position const& rhs) {std::cout << "Assign. " << id << " replaced with " << rhs.id << "\n"; id = rhs.id;return *this;}` and retry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `vec2 = vec1`, `vec2` takes on copies of all the elements of `vec1`. How could it do that if it ceased to exist?

Now, as for `vec2`'s *elements*, they don't need to be destroyed when they can be copied/moved<sup>†</sup> over instead. The language allows either to happen.

If you write your own copy/move assignment operators and put debug output in those, you'll see what's *really* going on.

<sup><sup>†</sup> Depending on C++ version.</sup>

Comment: In other words - it is ok, I'm not get any leak?

Comment: @tower120: No, there is no leak. As I suggested, try it out for yourself!

Comment: Adding Move changes the behavior. Currently Position does not not have Move operations. As the compiler does not generate one if the destructor is user defined.

Comment: The OP is free to experiment with the various combinations.

Comment: @tower120: It's very hard to get a leak nowadays, because there's so little reason left to use `new`

Comment: @MSalters - really? You mean RAII?

Comment: @tower120: Yes, that, including smart pointers of varying constructions.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - is this shared_ptr/unique_ptr (which still require new)? Or I mistaken?

Comment: @tower120: Well, okay, fair point, you can still use `new` to construct those. Though you should use `make_shared` and `make_unique` instead. But beyond writing out the `new` keyword you're still absolved from manual memory management responsibilities. And in all other cases you just use automatic/static allocation, RAII and move semantics.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - new has one more plus! It's easier just to typo new, than all thoose constructions :) Plus they little slower than just new. And if there is many small short-living objects little may become significant.

Comment: @tower120: Sorry, what's slower than what?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit construction of 100000 objects with shared_ptr/unique_ptr, setting owner against single "new" call.

Comment: @tower120: Well, on such a scale, you just wouldn't do that. You wouldn't individually `new` 100,000 objects, either...

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - Thats right :) I use pool. In pool I generate them with new placement(that which for allocation). And then when comes the time init them with constructor (another new). But thats all offtopic :)

Answer (score 3):

The container requirements (C++11 23.2.1) for assignment say:

> All existing elements of a are either move assigned to or destroyed

(Actually that is only for assignment of an rvalue. For assignment of an lvalue, there's no specification at all other than that the two containers shall be equal afterwards.)

So it's up to the implementation whether the original elements are destroyed, or overwritten element-wise.

If you want to destroy the original container and replace it with a copy of another container unconditionally, you can use `swap` like so:

```
// instead of "x = y"

std::vector<Position>(y).swap(x);
```

This constructs a new vector as a copy of `y` and swaps that with `x`, and swapping doesn't touch the actual container elements - again from the container requirements:

> `a.swap(b)` shall exchange the values of a and b without invoking any move, copy, or swap operations on the individual container elements

Answer (score 2):

Adding more print statements for compiler generated functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Don't have this on my machine so added
// to make it similar to the original
std::ostream& qDebug()
{
    return std::cout;
}

struct Position{
    int id;
    Position(int _id){
        id = _id;
        qDebug()<<"Position"<<id <<"\n";
    }

    ~Position(){
        qDebug()<<"~Position "<<id <<"\n";
    }


    // Added this. Because if you don't define one
    // the compiler will.
    // Made it do the default action and print
    Position(Position const& rhs)
        : id(rhs.id)
    {
        qDebug() <<"Copy: " << id <<"\n";
    }

    // Added this. Because if you don't define one
    // the compiler will.
    // Made it do the default action and print
    Position& operator=(Position const& rhs)
    {
        qDebug() << "Assign: Old(" << id << ")  New(" << rhs.id << ")\n";
        id = rhs.id;
        return *this;
    }
};



int main()
{
    qDebug()<<"Init\n";
    std::vector<Position> vec1;
    vec1.emplace_back(1);
    std::vector<Position> vec2;
    vec2.emplace_back(2);
    std::vector<Position> vec3;
    vec3.emplace_back(3);

    qDebug()<<"Move\n";
    vec2 = vec1;

    qDebug()<<"---------------------------------\n";
}
```

Now we run it:

```
> ./a.out
Init
Position1
Position2
Position3
Move
Assign: Old(2)  New(1)
---------------------------------
~Position 3
~Position 1
~Position 1
```

So we can see that Position(2) got overwritten by an assignment that placed (1) into the value. The most important thing to note is that the number of constructors and destructors match.

Comment: Why compiler need operator = to move? Why it do not use move constructor, instead?

Comment: @tower120: Because when you define a destructor the compiler will not generate a move constructor automatically. This will prevent the compiler for generating on move on the vectors. If you define the Move constructor then the compiler has the option to use the move on the vector as well. Notice this example is a bit contrived as the destructor simply prints information (so this class in reality would have a move constructor).

Comment: But note: In this case you can not use move. This is because the old vector is still around and usable. Moving the content from one array to the other would have left the rhs array in an undefined state (or the elements are in an undefined state).

Comment: I ask this, because I just tried to add move constructor (noexcept and so on) , but std::vector call operator=. Ahh - never mind. Probably another situation. Thanks.

Comment: @tower120: Moves are more visible when you return an object by value from a function. `vec[0] = FuncRetunsPositionByValue();` This is because after the return the value is of no use inside the function so moving it will not cause problems. But note RVO and NRVO also kick in so you have to devise situations like above to see it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Your class position has no explicitly defined copy-assignment operator. When this statement

vec2 = vec1;

is executed the copy assignment operator for elements the number of which is common for the both vectors is called. So vec2[0] is substituted for vec1[0] (that is vec1[0] is assigned to vec2[0]). It means that old element vec2[0] gets id equal to 1. Nothing is deleted.

When destructors are called vec2[0] has id equal to 1 and vec1[0] has id equal to 1 because this element was assigned to vec2[0]. The output shows this.